# Swapping an array to its original state

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I have been performing array related test where I try to swap array following a specific pattern and then I try to swap the array back to how it was originally using the pattern in reverse it always worked. As I was performing my tests I ran into a tricky situation where my reversal pattern simply wasn't doing the job! I have decided to post my problem here to see if anyone has any insight into what it is I am missing when I try to reverse my array! is the array not reversible?

The array along with the swapping pattern:

```
String[] strs = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        for(int i = 0; i<strs.length-2; i++){
            String temp = strs[i];
            strs[i] = strs[i+2];
            strs[i+2] = temp;

            for(int r = 0; r<strs.length-6; r++){
                String temp2 = strs[r];
                strs[r] = strs[r+6];
                strs[r+6] = temp2;

                for(int s = 0; s<strs.length-4; s++){
                    String temp3 = strs[s];
                    strs[s] = strs[s+4];
                    strs[s+4] = temp3;

                    for(int t = 0; t<strs.length-2; t++){
                        String temp4 = strs[t];
                        strs[t] = strs[t+2];
                        strs[t+2] = temp4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Result: G B E H I N M T O D A L S V Q P W F Y X C J K R U Z

I have originally try to revert back the array using the same formula in reverse
but even when it would compile without index out of bounds exceptions it will still not revert the array back to its original state!

```
 for(int i = 0; i<strs.length; i++)
        System.out.print(strs[i]+" ");
        System.out.println("");

        for(int i = strs.length-3; i>=0; i--){
            String temp = strs[i];
            strs[i] = strs[i+2];
            strs[i+2] = temp;

            for(int r = strs.length-7; r>=0; r--){
                String temp2 = strs[r];
                strs[r] = strs[r+6];
                strs[r+6] = temp2;

                for(int s = strs.length-5; s>=0; s--){
                    String temp3 = strs[s];
                    strs[s] = strs[s+4];
                    strs[s+4] = temp3;

                    for(int t = strs.length-3; t>=0; t--){
                        String temp4 = strs[t];
                        strs[t] = strs[t+2];
                        strs[t+2] = temp4;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        for(int i = 0; i<strs.length; i++)
        System.out.print(strs[i]+" ");
```

Result: G N O P W R E B C H A D I T Q Z K L M V S F Y J U X

Here is the Reversed version as suggested by

```
for(int i = 0; i<strs.length-2; i++){
            String temp = strs[i];
            strs[i] = strs[i+2];
            strs[i+2] = temp;

            for(int r = 0; r<strs.length-6; r++){
                String temp2 = strs[r];
                strs[r] = strs[r+6];
                strs[r+6] = temp2;

                for(int s = 0; s<strs.length-4; s++){
                    String temp3 = strs[s];
                    strs[s] = strs[s+4];
                    strs[s+4] = temp3;

                    for(int t = 0; t<strs.length-2; t++){
                        String temp4 = strs[t];
                        strs[t] = strs[t+2];
                        strs[t+2] = temp4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Result: I X Y B E N K T G P S D Q Z O F A H M V U L C J W R

Comment: I/O would be helpful.. but even more helpful would be comments and where you are actually getting the problem..

Comment: Well all that the methods are doing is swapping elements in the arrays in a series of nested for loops. The elements are all swapped at different places depending on the respective for loop. The problem is that my solution to reverting back the array to its original state is simply not doing that! The result I get is not the original array.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `for loop`s to be nested?

Comment: `originally using the pattern`, do you mean the memento-pattern?

Comment: @garnulf yes I want to achieve the best swap to make the array look shuffle

Comment: @PeterRader I am sorry I did not get the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reverse your previous algorithm, you also need to reverse the order of the blocks inside each loop  (first main swap, then inner loop) to (first inner loop then swap), like this:

```
      for(int i = strs.length-3; i>=0; i--)  {         

        for(int r = strs.length-7; r>=0; r--) {                

            for(int s = strs.length-5; s>=0; s--) {                   

                for(int t = strs.length-1; t>=3; t--) {                        
                    String temp4 = strs[t];
                    strs[t] = strs[t-3];
                    strs[t-3] = temp4;
                 }   

                String temp3 = strs[s];
                strs[s] = strs[s+4];
                strs[s+4] = temp3;                    
             }

            String temp2 = strs[r];
            strs[r] = strs[r+6];
            strs[r+6] = temp2; 
         }

        String temp = strs[i];
        strs[i] = strs[i+2];
        strs[i+2] = temp;
     }
```

This will actually put your array back in its original state.  Try it out.

Comment: Freaking awesome! that definitely did the trick. Thank you very much for your answer =)

Answer (score 4):

The reason why it's not reverting back to its original state is because your reversal algorithm is nested incorrectly.

Consider this pseudo-code, given that you have multiple nested `for` loops.

```
for 1 to 1
     System.out.println("Step 1");

         for 1 to 1
               System.out.println("Step 2")

                       for 1 to 1
                              System.out.println("Step 3")
```

When running this, it would print out Step 1, then Step 2, and then finally Step 3, right?

So when wanting to reverse your algorithm, you need to perfrom the steps in the reverse order. So Step 3 needs to be performed first, and then Step 2, and then finally Step 1.

This could be as simple as reversing the order of your nested for-loops, but it also could not be - I'm not entirely sure and to be honest don't really want to look into this too far because my mind starts hurting when theres so many nested for loops haha. But I hope this gets you on the right track, let me know if you have any questions.

On a side note, I'd highly recommend for you to consider rewriting some of this code - I'm not convinced that nested for loops are entirely necessary, and removing them would highly improve this code's readibility, which as you've probably noticed, is really really really important.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I believe I have try what you are suggesting without the desired result but maybe I did it wrong. I will give it another try and I ll post my results. Thank you for your time =)

Comment: @ Ted I have now added your recommended solution along with the result and compiled! I guess it is more complicated than originally thought. =)

Answer (score 1):

I want to avoid writing the solution code for you in this case, but the problem has to do with the starting positions of the loop for your reversal code. Double check those positions, use a debugger (if you are working with an IDE, most have these built in), and walk through the code line by line.

What you'll find is that you're not starting in the correct position.

In addition, it's best practice to always use braces after any loop or conditional. I noticed in your code that you had two cases of this that can lead to a lot of confusion for your reader. Plus, it'll help you readjust to the code down the road. In your reverse code:

```
for(int i = 0; i<strs.length; i++)
    System.out.print(strs[i]+" ");
    System.out.println("");

// Other loops...

for(int i = 0; i<strs.length; i++)
    System.out.print(strs[i]+" ");
```

becomes

```
for(int i = 0; i<strs.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(strs[i]+" ");
}
System.out.println("");

// Other loops...

for(int i = 0; i<strs.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(strs[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: I will look closer into your suggestion. Thank you for your time

Comment: You should also consider @Milton Hernandez answer. I avoided writing a working solution for you, but I believe his might be what you want.